# How to implement admin becoming another user temporarily?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sorcery

I have a traditional Rails 4 app with a User model and Sorcery for authentication.  The User model has an 'admin' flag.  What's the best way to implement the ability for admins to temporarily become another user (in order to see what the user sees to help debug a problem) and then pop back to being their original, admin-enabled user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's a implementation:

http://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-masquerade-as-another-user-to-see-how-they-use-yo

I think this was what you were looking for

Comment: A reasonably elegant solution, and presented as auth-library-netural.  I'll give it the checkmark.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know about rails, but under Unix, your executable needs to be allowed to switch between user modes. That is done by setting the 's' bit on your executables and setting up the owner and/or group to what is required to do whatever you want the application to be capable of. (i.e. most often you use root as the owner and srwxr-xr-x as the permissions, which is 4755 as a mode number).

Once you have that in place, your application can use the function `setuid(<uid>)`. If you use root, the <uid> would be 0 (zero).

Under Linux you have `seteuid()`, `setfsuid()`, and `setreuid()` as well.

To make sure you're doing the right thing, I suggest that you read the corresponding manual pages.

Comment: I'm sorry if I did not make this clear, but I am not talking about unix system users. I'm talking about users on a website, each of which have a record in a 'users' table in a relational database.

Comment: Ah! Then I guess I cannot help. Without a better knowledge of how your system logs users in... you won't be able to do it. In the CMS I'm working on, the code can always read anything available in the database. However, I can call a function to test whether any given user (by default, the current user) has access to view/modify/delete that data.

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with this matter, but perhaps you can add a superuser flag to your User model. If you are a superuser you can adjust the admin flag. The only point of the superuser is just to be able to turn admin rights off or on. Now you can switch between being an user or an admin and see what the user sees. Once done you enable admin and you get your admin interface back.

This would work, but I don't know if it is the best solution for your use case. Just theorycrafting here. :)

Comment: That would allow you to see things as *a* user, not a particular user.  I want to become a particular user, as if I had logged in as them.  This is easy to implement.  The challenge is how to pop back to your original identity -- have the system remember that you were an admin, and allow you to restore that state.

Comment: Think the equivalent of "su <username>" on linux.