# Ruby-Login with Run as a different user in browser

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, rspec, automation, cucumber

Normally with hand, <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>right-click</kbd> on browser - Run as a different user.

Login by typing user name and password. I'm testing Ruby. How do I log in with different users in Ruby?

[image]

Comment: You can check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/24952345/2067375. This might be helpful . You need to implement that feature in the application itself.

Comment: Thanks but That's not what I'm looking for